# Is it true that $p \in \operatorname{Iso}(X)$ iff $\{p\}$ is an open set?

Tags: general-topology

I have the following definition and statement in my lecture notes

**Definition of isolated point:**

A point $p \in E $ is called an isolated point of $E$ if there exists $U \in \mathfrak{U}_p$ ie a neighborhood of the point p, such that $U \cap E=\{p\}$. The set of isolated points of $E$ is denoted with $\operatorname{Iso}(E)$.

**Then they give the following statement:**

Note that $p \in \operatorname{Iso}(X)$ iff $\{p\}$ is an open set: for example, if $\tau$ is the discrete topology, each point is isolated and $Der(E)=\emptyset$, for any $E$.($\operatorname{Der}(E)$ is the derived set of E)

**My question**
Is there something wrong with  this last statement? They are saying $\{p\}$ is open no matter the topology. I agree for the discrete topology, but not for others like, for example if $\tau$ is the usual euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ , since the open sets are open balls, there is no way an open ball is contained in $\{p\}$, so how can it be open? If I am wrong, why is "$p \in \operatorname{Iso}(X)$ iff $\{p\}$" true?

Comment: $p \in \textrm{Iso}(X)$ iff $\{p\}$ is an open set *in $X$* (this also covers the relatively  open case)

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma To prove the part $Der(E)=\emptyset$. I did like this: by definition  $p \in Der(E): $iff $\forall $open set $U$ containing $p$,   $ U\setminus\{ p \} \cap E \neq \emptyset$, but the definition doesn't hold because since $\{ p \}$ is an open set, I can take $U= \{ p \}$, so that $ U\setminus\{ p \} \cap E = \emptyset$, so $Der(E)=\emptyset$, does it look ok?

Comment: yes, taking $U=\{p\}$ refutes that the isolated point is a derivative point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is an isolated point, then there is an open set $U$ such that $U\cap X=\{p\}$. But since $X$ is the whole space, $U\subseteq X$, and so $U\cap X=U$ and so $U=\{p\}$, and so $\{p\}$ is indeed open.

Alternatively, $p$ is an isolated point of $E$ if and only if $\{p\}$ is open in the subspace topology.

Comment: I understand the proof which is general, but why does it look wrong in a concrete example like:  $X= (1,2) \cup \{3\}$? and the euclidean topology, We know $\{3\} \in Iso(X)$, then by the statement,$\{3\}$ should be an open set,but I know that single points in the euclidean topology are closed , that is, there is no neighborhood of $3$, that is, no open ball in one dimension centered at $3$. And who do prove the converse?

Comment: But it is open, the ball $(2.5,3.5)$ is just that. As I said, $3$ is an isolated point because it is *relatively open*.

Comment: all right and why is $Der(E)=\emptyset$ for any $E$?

Comment: Because of how the derived set is defined.

Comment: To the proposer: $\{3\}$ is not open in the space $\Bbb R$ but it is open in the space $X$. Sets are not intrinsically open or not open. Also a set may be both open and closed.